# Is R-symmetry an internal symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, supersymmetry

[R-symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-symmetry) need not be a symmetry of a supersymmetric theory. However, if we make it a symmetry of our theory, is it an internal symmetry in the same sense that $SU(3)_c$ is an internal symmetry of QCD? (Though, not necessarily a gauge symmetry.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes, it is a correct way to think about it. $R$-symmetry is a global symmetry of the the theory. For the $N=1$ it is typically $U(1)$ symmetry, which acts by multiplication by phase. And as for extended supersymmetry, when we consider action on fields, it is a flavor symmetry in some sense. For instance, the $N=4$ gauge multiplet has a following content:
$$
\underbrace{g_{+}}_{1 \ \text{gluon}} \qquad 
\underbrace{\lambda^{A}}_{4 \ \text{gluino}} \qquad 
\underbrace{\varphi^{A B}}_{6 \ \text{scalars}} \qquad 
\underbrace{\lambda^{A B C}}_{4 \ \text{gluino}} \qquad 
\underbrace{g_{-}^{1 2 3 4}}_{1 \ \text{gluon}}
$$
Gauge fields are singlets (do not transform). Fermions form a fundamental(antifundamental) quartet under $SU(4)$, and scalars transform in the vector representation of $SU(4)$.